# Multiple checkable groups in NavigationDrawer stopped working after upgrading support design library

Tags: android, navigationview, android-support-design, navigation-drawer

I am using NavigationView to display menu.xml data to my NavigationDrawer. It had two groups of checkable items. The first group could have any number of items checked at the same time, the second one could have only one checked.

Support library versions used:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

xml code used for NavigationView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:checkableBehavior="all" android:id="@+id/navgroup_layers" android:menuCategory="container">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_traffic"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_traffic_light"
        android:title="@string/Traffic"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_text"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tooltip_text"
        android:title="@string/text_labels"/>
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/navgroup_cities"
       android:checkableBehavior="single"
       android:menuCategory="container"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_berlin"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_traffic_light"
        android:title="@string/berlin"/>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_prague"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_subway"
    android:checked="false"
    android:title="@string/prague"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_paris"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tooltip_text"
        android:title="@string/paris"/>
</group>
```

After I upgraded the libraries to the newest:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

The checkable behavior changed. Now, when I click on the same item multiple times, it checks and unchecks itself, but when I select a different item, everything gets unchecked and only after another click on the same item, it gets checked. 
After looking at the source code of the two versions, I could not realize what the problem was. It looks a bit like this chackable behavior attribute is not considered at all in the new version. A bug of the lib or the whole implementation should be suddenly done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 23 of `NavigationView` did entirely change the structure of how the menu is built - it is now based upon [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) as mentioned in the comments of the [release Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/RZutBRWN6sH).

From the [NavigationMenuPresenter's Adapter source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#310) (which controls how menu items are displayed and stored), it appears only a single checked item is saved and checking one item does uncheck other checked items.

This would require a [new bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Support%20Library%20bug) to be filed to get `NavigationView` to take into account the `checkableBehavior` field.