# 2 single checkable groups in android menu

Tags: android, menu

I have two groups in Android, both with single checkable behaviour.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/sort_item"
    android:title="One">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_group_sort"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sort_new"
                android:title="@string/menu_new" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sort_hot"
                android:title="@string/menu_hot" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sort_top"
                android:title="@string/menu_top" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_item"
    android:title="Two">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_group_filter"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_all"
                android:title="@string/menu_all" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_business"
                android:title="@string/menu_business" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_technology"
                android:title="@string/menu_technology" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_politics"
                android:title="@string/menu_politics" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

What I want is when you select an item from one group, it is 'single' within that group. What is happening is that both groups are sharing 'what' is selected, and it's not working properly at all.

I've read all the other posts about this, and none of the solutions (if any) worked. Does anyone know? This seems like a pretty basic thing..

Comment: Can you post your code in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` where you set the selected item checked?  I copied your menu XML into an app of mine, added this statement:`item.setChecked(true);`, and it works as expected--the items from each group are not coupled.

Comment: @qbix it's actually using NavigationView, so onNavigationItemSelected. I never call setChecked(true); because the NavigationView I think does it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the NavigationDrawer (version 23), as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571192/2503185)

> Version 23 of NavigationView did entirely change the structure of how
>   the menu is built - it is now based upon RecyclerView as mentioned in
>   the comments of the release Google+ post.
>
> From the NavigationMenuPresenter's Adapter source code (which controls
>   how menu items are displayed and stored), it appears only a single
>   checked item is saved and checking one item does uncheck other checked
>   items.

I would go all the way back to 22.0.0 in my build.gradle:

```
com.android.support:design:22.0.0
```

Or make a manual validation of the checked items in the `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` function.

Comment: You're right that it's a bug, but manually setting menuItem.setChecked(true|false); in onNavigationItemSelected *does not work*. I will try onDrawerOpened instead... do you know how I can manually change the selected style? I might have to even manually apply the style to the correct items..

Comment: Oh, @automation I was able to use `setChecked(true)` when I rolled back to 23.0.0 I used your menu XML layout and this snippet: http://pastebin.com/iXrT936Q